# Solve the equation $x^x=10^9$.

Tags: calculus, roots

The main question was to solve $x\log_{10}{x}=9$. I reduced it to this equation. This is $x$ Degree equation. How to solve this? I know this can be solved by newton's method. But I am not getting how to apply it.

Comment: The standard approach is the W-function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Example_2

Comment: You can also use binary search (bisection method) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Arkamis proposes, you need [Lambert's W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Then [$x^x=10^9 \to x=e^{W(\ln 10^9)}=9.2950869003762184...$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e2r2um1d5d2)

Answer (score 5):

To solve numerically just follow the standard newton raphson method steps:

$$ y =x^x$$

$$y ' = x^x ( \ln x +1 )$$

$$ x \leftarrow x - \frac{y-10^9}{y'} = x - \frac{1 - 10^9 x^{-x}}{\ln x + 1} $$

Answer (score 4):

If you use Newton's method, you are looking for a zero of $x^x-10^9$ by considering $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$ and in this case $f(x)=x^x-10^9$ with $f'(x)=x^x(\log_e(x)+1)$.

You need to decide a starting point and obviously $9^9 \lt 10^9 \lt 10^{10}$ so $9$ or $10$ or something between them would do.  For example

```
x_n         f(x_n)      f'(x_n)
9           -612579511  1238670309
9.49454605  908419550.2 6203732894
9.34811493  186970498.1 3840056939
9.29942542  14110834.53 3275529942
9.29511747  98716.84972 3229808064
9.29508690  4.922117114 3229485986
```

or

```
x_n         f(x_n)      f'(x_n)
10          9000000000  33025850930
9.72748620  3080960913  13364965418
9.49696104  923461012.5 6253117619
9.34928094  191456569.3 3854718766
9.29961284  14724904.42 3277533809
9.29512016  107408.813  3229836424
9.29508690  5.826986194 3229485989
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet, I'd say, is to recast the problem as looking for a zero of the function

$$f(x)=x\ln x-9\ln10$$

The Newton-Raphson iteration, $x\to x-(f(x)/f'(x))$ is

$$x\to{x+9\ln10\over1+\ln x}$$

Since $9\ln9\lt9\ln10\lt10\ln10$, we know the zero is between $9$ and $10$, so it's sensible to split the difference and start at $x=9.5$.  Then you get

$$\begin{align}
9.5&\to{9.5+9\ln10\over1+\ln9.5}\approx9.29577\\
9.29577&\to{9.29577+9\ln10\over1+\ln9.29577}\approx9.2950869\\
\end{align}$$

etc.